# Visual Basic 2010 Listbox Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

what is the meaning of this error? sorry it's my first time to use Visual basic 2010, I'm not familiar with this kind of error, I use this for selecting all the files in the listbox and tried to move or copy to another listbox in other form.

> Error 1   'ToArray' is not a member of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.

This is the code I use.

> Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
>   System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click
>
> If RadioButton1.Checked Then
>
> ```
>         Dim itemsToMove = ListBox1.Items.ToArray()
>         For Each item In itemsToMove
>             Form2.lstP.Items.Add(item)
>             ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
>         Next
>         Form2.Show()
>     End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

What the error means is that [Listbox.ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx)  does not have a method or property called *ToArray*. So, you can't call the *ToArray* on this collection. It is not clear why you want to do this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cast the ListBox to an array.  If you need to know the number of items in the list you can do the following

```
    Dim itemsToMove As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
```

Otherwise that line of code Dim itemsToMove = ListBox1.Items.ToArray() is not necessary.   You can simply use

```
    For Each item In ListBox1
        Form2.lstP.Items.Add(item)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
    Next
```